# How do wizards creating potions determine the effects of their potion, and whether it will work or not?

Tags: harry-potter, potions

My question derives from the medical and science field. All mixtures coming and going are tested to see if they are effective or not. Using this logic, the same applies to the potion being created in the wizarding world (although the Muggle and Wizard worlds are literally worlds apart).

So how do wizards creating potions determine the effects of their potion, and whether it will work or not?

Comment: Hi, the body of your question is different from the title. I think the body actually asks what you're looking for, so maybe you should edit the title to reflect that.

Comment: @Spencer Give me a moment. :)

Comment: @Spencer Is this better?

Comment: Is your question about the ingredients to potions and how their effects were discovered, or are you asking how potion-makers managed to figure out the recipes for the first potions?

Comment: My favorite sci-fi/fantasy author tackled that question– Poul Anderson. In his books Three Hearts and Three Lions, Operation Chaos, and Operation Luna, he created a world where magic is based on might be called natural science. He explains why elements like silver and iron work against magical beings, the physiology of creatures like werewolves and trolls, and, in the Chaos books, had people into applied and theoretical magic attend college, conduct laboratory experiments, and earned degrees in specialties like linguistics (spells) and cryptozoology. I wish more authors took the time he did.

Comment: @fez I mean: after they made their potions, how did they know what would happen if someone drank the potion without force-feeding it.

Comment: Trial and error, and a lot of self-testing I would assume... Looking forward to see if there's an actual canon answer!

Comment: They're tested by the Ministry of Potions and Lotions labs to receive the MQA (Magical Quality Assurance) seal of approval.

Comment: @FreeMan Make that an answer?

Comment: Oh, I would, @Silvermidnight, but I've got exactly bupkiss to support it and I'd get a ruler across my knuckles for the effort (or lack thereof). Therefore, it will have to remain a snarky comment.

Comment: Self-testing? This is why one has apprentices!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An experienced potion-maker appears to be able to tell whether a potion has been brewed correctly based on a range of factors; colour, consistency and smell.

> Slughorn moved slowly between the tables, peering into cauldrons. He
> made no comment, but **occasionally gave the potions a stir, or a sniff.**
> At last he reached the table where Harry, Ron, Hermione and Ernie were
> sitting. He smiled ruefully at the tarlike substance in Ron’s
> cauldron. He passed over Ernie’s navy concoction. Hermione’s potion he
> gave an approving nod. Then he saw Harry’s, and a look of incredulous
> delight spread over his face.
>
> ‘The clear winner!’ he cried to the dungeon. ‘Excellent, excellent,
> Harry! Good Lord, it’s clear you’ve inherited your mother’s talent,
> she was a dab hand at Potions, Lily was! Here you are, then, here you
> are – one bottle of Felix Felicis, as promised, and use it well!’

In the films, Slughorn drops in a leaf to see if it burns up. Evidently he likes what he sees.